# How come phoenix.js doesn't create an instance of a websocket class in js?

Tags: websocket, phoenix-framework

I'm looking at the client used in phoenix, phoenix.js file.

How come I don't see a reference to code like:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("...");
```

Doesn't it have to create a websocket class?

The only reference I see is here:
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/662d5630026ea523a62f7d1e35912ca461397ddc/priv/static/phoenix.js#L226

I'm just trying to understand how it creates the client as per the WebSocket class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Hoping someone can clarify how the phoenix.js creates a websocket connection, and I am assuming it is cross-browser also.

Answer (score 2):

It does create a `WebSocket` instance. In [line 895](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/662d5630026ea523a62f7d1e35912ca461397ddc/priv/static/phoenix.js#L895), you'll see that `WebSocket` is stored in `this.transport`, falling back to `LongPoll` if WebSocket is not present:

```
this.transport = opts.transport || global.WebSocket || LongPoll;
```

Later in [line 994](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/662d5630026ea523a62f7d1e35912ca461397ddc/priv/static/phoenix.js#L994), there's a call to `new this.transport(...)`:

```
this.conn = new this.transport(this.endPointURL());
```